# When mocking a service, do I need to know exactly what it does and what each call returns?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

New to karma and jasmine, setting up tests on a project I'm not very familiar with. In order to mock a service in a controller test, do I need to set up fake functions that return data in the format expected? Or is there an easier way to do this than going back and forth trying to set up dummy data, etc

Comment: Yes. That's what Jasmine spies are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend getting Sinon.js, if you have Sinon all you have to do is get the interface and then you can tell it what each function should return in your tests.

Check out my answer for this post here.

[Jasmine, Karma, Angular how to write test on my Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919377/jasmine-karma-angular-how-to-write-test-on-my-angular-app/36946058#36946058)