# AngularJS Controller Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I new in AngularJS and try Unit Testing.I am using Karma and Jasmine. I created the first test for my controller but its not working and I don't know why karma throughs an error.

So please help me out this.

**BasicTabCtrl.js**

```
// Basic Tab Controller 
myApp.controller('BasicTabCrtl', ['$scope', '$modal', 'BasicTabService', function ($scope, $modal, BasicTabService) {
    console.log("BAsic tab crtl");

    $scope.name = 'testing';
    $scope.tab1 = "BASIC";
    $scope.tab2 = "ADVANCE";
    $scope.tab3 = "FORM";

    $scope.user = {};
    // get user from service
    $scope.Tablelist = BasicTabService.getUser();

    // delete user
    $scope.deleteUser = function (obj) {
        console.log("OBJ => " + JSON.stringify(obj));
        if (obj != -1) {
            $scope.Tablelist.splice(obj, 1);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is my test case

**example.js**

```
describe('myApp',function(){
 var scope,controller;

 beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp');
 });

  describe('BasicTabCrtl',function(){

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller=$controller('BasicTabCrtl',{
            '$scope':scope
        });
        console.log("d");
    }));

    it('set the name',function(){
        expect(scope.name).toBe('testing');
    });

  });

});
```

**Error**

```
26 05 2016 20:47:50.890:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/test/example.js".
Firefox 46.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) myApp BasicTabCrtl set the tab1 name FAILED
    minErr/<@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular.js:68:12
    loadModules/<@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular.js:4587:15
    forEach@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular.js:322:11
    loadModules@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular.js:4548:5
    createInjector@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular.js:4470:19
    workFn@/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/static/js/angular-mocks.js:2954:44
    TypeError: scope is undefined in /home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/test/example.js (line 19)
    @/home/rahul/Documents/django_project/myfirstsite/test/example.js:19:3
Firefox 46.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.023 secs / 0.018 secs)
```

Comment: you miss spelled `$controller`

Comment: sorry for this but not working

Comment: It looks like it failed to load one or more modules. Is your Karma file pointing to all needed js files?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the injection isn't working because of missing `_` around angular methods

```
describe('myApp',function(){
 var scope,controller;

 beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp');
 });

  describe('BasicTabCrtl',function(){

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        controller = $controller('BasicTabCrtl',{
            '$scope':scope
        });
        console.log("d");
    }));

    it('set the name',function(){
        expect(scope.name).toBe('testing');
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**Create controller instance :**

```
callController = function () {
        return $controller('BasicTabCrtl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $routeParams: routeParams
        });
      };
```

Then test that it's defined or not . If this test pass then you can continue with unit test.

```
describe('null test', function () {
    it('controller should be defined', function () {
      ctrl = callController();
      expect(ctrl).to.not.be.undefined;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are not injecting all of the dependencies when you instantiate your controller.  Try this...

```
beforeEach(inject(['$scope', '$modal', 'BasicTabService', '$controller', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $modal, BasicTabService, $controller, $rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller=$controller('BasicTabCrtl',{
        '$scope':$scope,
        '$modal':$modal,
        'BasicTabService': BasicTabService
    });
    console.log("d");
}));
```

Try my answer from [Jasmine, Karma, Angular how to write test on my Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919377/jasmine-karma-angular-how-to-write-test-on-my-angular-app/36946058#36946058).  I describe how to test controllers and services and directives.