# Karma/Jasmine/Angular-Mocks "not a function got string"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running some unit tests based off of this website: http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/19/karma-angularjs-testing/

I've wrote an app.js file and a MathController.js file.

Enclosed is the relevant code:

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router', 'ng-resource', 'ui-bootstrap']);
   // app.config stuff here
}());
```

**MathController.js**

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').controller('MathController', ['$scope', function ($scope){

        $scope.sum = function(){
            $scope.z = $scope.x + $scope.y;
        };

    }]);
}());
```

And here is the test spec file:

**MathController.spec.js**

```
describe('MathController', function(){

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject('app'));
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;    
    }));


    it('should equal 3', function(){
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('MathController', {$scope: $scope });
        $scope.x = 1;
        $scope.y = 2;
        $scope.sum();
        expect($scope.z).toBe(3);
    });

});
```

And this is the error I get in the console:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) MathController should equal 3 FAILED
    Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string (line 22)

.....some extra stuff omitted
    workFn@/root/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2401:26
    undefined
    Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/ng/areq?p0=MathController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined in /home/root/lib/angular/angular.min.js (line 22)
.....some extra stuff omitted
    /home/root/spec/MathController.spec.js:13:31
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.041 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

So it says MathController is not a function, and it says angular picked up a string when it should have picked up a function.
Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to fix this?

Comment: Your code example doesn't match the one you linked to or the [official guidelines for creating tests](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) (neither example use `angular.mock.inject`).

Comment: Following your lead, I tried module and inject as opposed angular.mock.inject, and now I get this error:

 `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$controller('MathController', {$scope: $scope })') in /home/root/spec/MathController.spec.js (line 13)`

Comment: Check out my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919377/jasmine-karma-angular-how-to-write-test-on-my-angular-app/36946058#36946058 It will have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this?

```
describe('MathController', function(){

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;    
    }));


    it('should equal 3', function(){
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('MathController', {$scope: $scope });
        $scope.x = 1;
        $scope.y = 2;
        $scope.sum();
        expect($scope.z).toBe(3);
    });

});
```

The difference being: angular.mock.module('app')

Comment: Hello, I appreciated your Pluralsight tutorial on ngMock! Anyways, I tried your suggestion. There is a new error message: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$controller('MathController', {$scope: $scope })') in /home/root/spec/MathController.spec.js`

Comment: Hmm, could be config. Double check your karma config file, the ordering is important:  files: [
  'lib/angular.min.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/*.js',
  'tests/*.js'
],