# Testing Angular Controller that is dependent on a factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Unit Testing, I am trying to test a controller that is dependent  on a factory that makes the calls to a URL to fetch data.

Below is my controller code(The sqResultReviewTable module code is in a separate file):

```
    (function () {
angular.module('sqResultReviewTable')
       .controller('sqResultReviewTableController', fetchJsonData);  //fetchJsonData is the controller function name.
function fetchJsonData($scope, fetchDataFromJsonFile) {              // fetchDataFromJsonFile is the the service that return the data that is fetched fron the JSON file.
    labResultData = fetchDataFromJsonFile.getOrders().then(function (returnedArray) {   //function call to the service method getOrders and storing the resultant array in a varaible called labResultData.
        $scope.labResultData = returnedArray;                   //Assigning labresultData to the $scope.
        console.log($scope.labResultData);
    });
}
})()
```

And here is my factory service(The factory service is in a separate file):

```
    (function () {
angular.module('sqResultReviewTable')
.factory('fetchDataFromJsonFile', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getOrders: function () {                //getOrders is function which can be used to fetch data from the JSON file. It return an Array.
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/ResultReview/GetDataFromService',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return JSON.parse(response.data);           //Returning the array that is fetched from the JSON file.
            });
        }
    };
}]);
})();
```

Below is test case that I have tried:

```
    describe('sqResultReviewTable', function () {    
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sqResultReviewTable'));
var $controller;
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));
describe('resultReviewTableController', function () {
    it('should have an array of length 4', function () {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('sqResultReviewTableController', { $scope: $scope });
        var len = $scope.labResultData.length;
        expect(len).toBe(4);
    });
});
});
```

I am getting this error:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 1:
I also tried in this manner, but the result is same
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
    describe('resultReviewTableController', function () {
beforeEach(module('sqResultReviewTable'));
var $scope;
describe('Table Controller', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('sqResultReviewTableController', {$scope : $scope});
    }));
    it('should contain an array of length 4', function () {
        expect($scope.labResultData.length).toBe(4);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: [Try my Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919377/jasmine-karma-angular-how-to-write-test-on-my-angular-app/36946058#36946058)