# Unit testing and mocking a service with DI

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I have been struggling with this for a while, and I'm hoping someone can help. I have a component that uses a service to get data. I am attempting to add unit tests to it. My problem is that the tests always fail with "Error: No provider for Http". Here is my code:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Contact } from './contact.model';

@Injectable()
export class ContactsService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getContacts(): Observable<Array<Contact>> {
        return this.http.get('assets/contacts.json').map(res => {
            let r = res.json().Contacts;
            return r;
        });
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Contact } from '../contact.model'; 
import { ContactsService } from '../contacts.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
    providers: [ContactsService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

    contactsAll: Array<Contact>;
    contacts: Array<Contact>;

    constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe((x) => {
            this.contactsAll = x;
            this.contacts = this.contactsAll;
        });
    }
```

}

Tests:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts.component';
import { ContactsService } from '../contacts.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact.model';

class MockContactsService extends ContactsService {

    constructor() {
        super(null);
    }

    testContacts: Array<Contact> = [
        new Contact("test1 mock", 12345, 10000),
        new Contact("test2 mock", 23456, 20000)
    ];

    public getContacts(): Observable<Array<Contact>> {
        return Observable.of(this.testContacts);
    }
}

describe('ContactsComponent', () => {
    let component: ContactsComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactsComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule],
            declarations: [ContactsComponent],
           // providers: [{ provide: ContactsService, useClass: MockContactsService }] // this is needed for the service mock
        }).overrideComponent(ContactsService, {// The following is to override the provider in the @Component(...) metadata
            set: {
                providers: [
                    { provide: ContactsService, useClass: MockContactsService },
                ]
            }
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactsComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('1st test', () => {
        it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
    })
});
```

Comment: I am getting `No provider for ContactsService!` with your code. Which version angular are you using?

Comment: I see strange code `.overrideComponent(ContactsService,` I would write `.overrideComponent(ContactsComponent,`

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919377/jasmine-karma-angular-how-to-write-test-on-my-angular-app/36946058#36946058

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

First, move your providers array from your component to your NgModule. It's better to provide your services at the module level since it de-couples your providers from your component tree structure *(unless you specifically want to have a separate instance of a provider per component, and from your simplified use case, there's no need for a separate instance per component).*

so,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
   /// providers: [ContactsService]  <-- remove this line
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
   .....
```

and add it to the NgModule that declares your ContactsComponent

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: ..
    declarations: ...
    providers: [ContactsService] // <-- provider definition moved to here
 })
 export class ModuleDeclaringContactsComponent
```

Once you do that, then mocking the ContactsService in your test is easy to implement.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [FormsModule],
        declarations: [ContactsComponent],
        providers: [{ provide: ContactsService, useClass: MockContactsService }] // this is needed for the service mock
    });
```

With that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Well, this is annoying - I have refactored the code as above, but I still get the same error - 'No provider for Http'. I then tried to create a plunker project so I could demonstrate what was happening, but the tests work on that page. The plunker link is https://plnkr.co/edit/NzrT9mG9mPIVVw2jvhP3?p=preview - I have used an existing example from Angular.io to get it to work.

Comment: try changing your MockContactsService not to inherit from the actual service class. It doesn't need to inherit - just has to have the properties that you intend to use in your test

Comment: I had the same problem and moving the provider from the component to the module seemed to have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone - turns out it was something completely different.

I modified my code as per snorkpete's answer, and I am going to mark that as the answer, as I believe that is the cleanest approach.

The real problem came from using Angular Cli to create my project. It automatically created tests for my component and my service. This meant the code in the service test was causing the error, not the code in the component. I commented out the code in the service test and everything passed.

Annoyingly, there was no indication in any of the failures that this is where the error was coming from!

Answer (score 0):

In case if component should have Service in providers we can ovverride metadata by **TestBed.overrideComponent()**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
    providers: [ContactsService] // IF YOU NEED IT
})
```

we need to do next:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
        providers: [
            {provide: SomeService, useValue: SomeMock},
            provideMockStore({system: {userConfig: {viewSettings: {theme: ThemeName.light}}}} as any)
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    TestBed.overrideComponent(SomeComponent , { set: { providers: [{provide: SomeService, useValue: SomeMock}]}})
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

more info here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/dependency-injection/