# Unit test with angular 5. I am trying mock a service but I receive : "[object ErrorEvent] thrown"

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying mock a service but I receibe : "[object ErrorEvent] thrown".

I'm trying using the way proposed by snorkpete:

[Unit testing and mocking a service with DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549861/unit-testing-and-mocking-a-service-with-di)

This is the test that is returning the error:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyComponent1Component } from './my-component1.component';
import {MyService1Service} from '../../service/my-service1.service';
import {MyComponent2Component} from '../../components/my-component2/my-component2.component'


fdescribe('MyComponent1Component', () => {
  let component: MyComponent1Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent1Component>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent1Component,MyComponent2Component ],
      imports: [],
      providers: [{ provide: MyService1Service, useClass: MockService }]
    }) 
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent1Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

class MockService {
  
 id: 1;
 userId: 'ruben';
 body: 'test';
};
```

This is .ts component1 src/app/my-component1/my-component1.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit,Renderer2,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MyService1Service} from '../../service/my-service1.service';
import { Post } from '../../models/post';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component1',
  templateUrl: './my-component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component1.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent1Component implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("myButton") myButton: ElementRef;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private _myService1Service: MyService1Service) { }
  public messagge1: Post[];

  func1(){    
    this.renderer.addClass(this.myButton.nativeElement, "my-class");
    this._myService1Service.test();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this._myService1Service.getPost().subscribe(
      result =>{
        console.log("from component1")
        console.log(result);
        this.messagge1=result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

This is the html component1 src/app/my-component1/my-component1.component.html:

```html
<p>
  my-component1 works!
</p>

<button #myButton (click)="func1()">press me</button>
<app-my-component2 *ngIf="messagge1" [messagge1]="messagge1">loading...</app-my-component2>
```

This is the .ts component 2 src/app/components/my-component2/my-component2.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Post} from '../../models/post'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component2',
  templateUrl: './my-component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component2.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent2Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() messagge1: Post[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("from component2")
    console.log(this.messagge1);
  }

}
```

This is the html component2 src/app/my-component1/my-component1.component.html:

```html
<p>
  my-component2 works!
</p>
```

This is the model returning by the service, src/app/models/post.ts:

```js
export interface Post {
 
 id: number;
 userId: string;
 body: string;
 
}
```

This is the service, src/app/service/my-service1.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Post} from '../models/post';

@Injectable()
export class MyService1Service {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  test(){
    console.log("test");
  }

  getPost(){
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
 }
}
```

Can someone help me know why I receive the error and check if I am correctly implementing the snorkpete answer?

Thanks very much.

Comment: add "--sourcemaps=false" when you run your test

Comment: Hi Narm, I have added --sourcemaps=false (npm run test --sourcemaps=false) but I receive the same error, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
     beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent1Component);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            tick();
            fixture.detectChanges();
          }));
```

because service request on Oninit are asyncrone